# Normalizing nested JSON data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I made a bunch of attempts to normalize some JSON data that I'm working with, but I need help with it. Here is some sample data:

```
138 [{'id': 360014, 'default': False, 'name': 'Add/Remove User', 'raw_name': 'Add/Remove User', 'value': 'purpose_add/remove_user'}, {'id': 360014, 'default': False, 'name': 'Change Permissions', 'raw_name': 'Change Permissions', 'value': 'purpose_change_permissions'}, {'id': 360014, 'default': False, 'name': 'Failed Data Validation', 'raw_name': 'Failed Data Validation', 'value': 'purpose_failed_data_validation'}, {'id': 360014, 'default': False, 'name': 'Grant Access', 'raw_name': 'Grant Access', 'value': 'purpose_grant_access'}]
139 [{'id': 360014, 'default': False, 'name': '200 - OK', 'raw_name': '200 - OK', 'value': '200_-_ok'}, {'id': 360014, 'default': False, 'name': '201 - Created', 'raw_name': '201 - Created', 'value': '201_-_created'}, {'id': 360014, 'default': False, 'name': '400 - Bad Request', 'raw_name': '400 - Bad Request', 'value': '400_-_bad_request'}, {'id': 360014, 'default': False, 'name': '404 - Not Found', 'raw_name': '404 - Not Found', 'value': '404_-_not_found'}, {'id': 360014, 'default': False, 'name': '444 - No Response', 'raw_name': '444 - No Response', 'value': '444_-_no_response'}]
140 [{'id': 360014, 'default': False, 'name': 'Pi :: Flow', 'raw_name': 'Pi :: Flow', 'value': 'Pi____Flow'}, {'id': 360014, 'default': False, 'name': 'Pi :: CloudFlare', 'raw_name': 'Pi :: CloudFlare', 'value': 'Pi____cloudflare'}, {'id': 360014, 'default': False, 'name': 'Pi :: Other', 'raw_name': 'Pi :: Other', 'value': 'Pi____other'}, {'id': 360014, 'default': False, 'name': 'Platform :: Stackdriver', 'raw_name': 'Platform :: Stackdriver', 'value': 'platform____stackdriver'}, {'id': 360014, 'default': False, 'name': 'Platform :: AlertSite', 'raw_name': 'Platform :: AlertSite', 'value': 'platform____alertsite'}, {'id': 360014, 'default': False, 'name': 'Platform :: BigQuery', 'raw_name': 'Platform :: BigQuery', 'value': 'platform____bigquery'}, {'id': 360014, 'default': False, 'name': 'Platform :: Other', 'raw_name': 'Platform :: Other', 'value': 'platform____other'}]
```

There is one single field, named 'custom_field_options' in this data frame.  I think the problem is that there are a few levels of nesting. I don't know enough about JSON to really describe the issue better than that.

I tried those lines of code:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pd.io.json.json_normalize(a), orient='columns')
pd.io.json.json_normalize(filtered_df, record_path=None, meta=None, meta_prefix=None, record_prefix=None, errors='raise', sep='.')
json_normalize(a)
```

But I got following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

I tried this:

```
json_normalize(df[a])
```

I got this result:

```
ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only
```

I tried this:

```
flat = json_normalize(a['id'])
```

I got this back:

```
KeyError: 'id'
```

How can I achieve it?

```
########################################
### HERE IS ALL MY CODE

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize


# create SQL
query = "SELECT * FROM Google BigQuery Table"
print(query)

# login
df = pd.read_gbq(query, project_id='my_id', dialect='standard')
print(df)

# drop all fields except 'custom_field_options'
s = df[['custom_field_options']]
print(s)


df = s[s.astype(bool)]
print(df)


a = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(a)
```

Comment: Sounds like you might be passing your json payload as a `str` into the `json_normalize` function rather than parsing it beforehand. Can you confirm that that's not what you are doing?

Comment: I just updated my original post with all my code.  Again, I don't know enough about JSON to really answer your question.  I'm curious to learn, for sure.  I just don't know very much about this kind of stuff.